# Repcached for Win32 - has anyone built it?

Tags: c, winapi, memcached

I have finally got the green light to use Memcached in our project (after months of lobbying against a database-based caching solution - just don't ask...), however we will need to use Repcached as well to have backup copies of our data.  Has anyone built this for Win32?  We may end up using Linux in production, but development will very likely be taking place on Windows.

Any hints or pointers are gratefully received - there appear to be lots of .T files, which I presume is TCL?  That could be fun...

Comment: Hi man, this was some time ago. Did you find anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply patch from http://code.jellycan.com/memcached/ that makes memcached win32 capable. I have not tired it but may work.

Comment: Thanks, I might have a go at that when I have the time.  It's quite a lot of open heart surgery on the code, though, I suspect :-/